# How JVM works internally with follow expression: Object c = new SomeClass();

Tags: java, oop, jvm

Internally, when an object is created in Java, JVM create a reference to an object in heap memory. For example:

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
```

Here, it was created a variabel called "s" that reference *SomeClass* object.

But, how does it work in the example bellow?

```
Object o = new SomeClass();
```

In this case, does JVM create an object from *Object* class or create an object from *SomeClass*? Why don't i have access to methods in SomeClass?

Comment: `new SomeClass();` creates an object; `Object o` declares a variable.

Comment: please mark it as answer if my answer solved your prb. Thanks @lago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parent class reference (*Object class*) can be used to hold Child class(*Some class*) object but by using that reference, we can't call Child-specific methods.**

The type of the reference variable would determine the methods that it can invoke on the object. The compiler only looks the method based on reference type that's why you will not get other methods than object methods since you referenced as object.

This is a special one and It is called polymorphism in the OOP world. Polymorphism is nothing but taking many forms by an instance.

The most common use of polymorphism in OOP occurs when a parent class reference is used to refer to a child class object.

In your case, You referenced the someclass instance by its parent class object since all classes are inherited Object class of Java.

When you overide the parent clas method in your child class for an example, If you override the toString() method of Object class in your someclass child. then in compile-time, Compiler checks the method signature It will be based on reference type, You referenced as object so when the compiler checks the  method It will find the same signature in Object class, So it will not arise a compile time exception. In the runtime, JVM take care on method execution, It will look if any overiding in the child class, then it will execute the child class method implementation. This is how overriding happens in Java.

So basically, Compiler checks the signature in reference type class, So You can't call a method that is not defined in the referenced class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object o = new SomeClass();
```

In this case JVM will not create an object from Object class. It create an object from SomeClass and initialize it to Object class o which is super of every classes.